# Connecting the points on a coord_polar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts

I have a dataframe that I want to convert into a radar looking chart. Currently I can only have the points on the chart, but would like to connect them as well.

The following are the sample datasets:

```
u_df <- data.frame(a = 8, b = 9, c = 8, d = 5, e = 7)
u_df_transposed <- user_df %>% 
    gather(key = 'Attributes', value = "Scores", a:e) 

ggplot(u_df_transposed, aes(x= Attributes, y = Scores)) + geom_point() + coord_polar()
```

Ideally, I want something that resembles a radar chart with a scale of 1 to 10 for each variable in the "Attributes" column.

What is the easiest way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To connect your observations, simply add `geom_path()` to your ggplot object. To force a certain number of breaks in the radial axis, add 
`scale_y_continuous()`:

```
plt <- ggplot(u_df_transposed, aes(x= Attributes, y = Scores))
plt <- plt + geom_path() + geom_point()
plt <- plt + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(min(u_df_transposed$Scores), max(u_df_transposed$Scores), 10))
# if the breaks do not need to be flexible:
# plt <- plt + scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:10))
plt <- plt + coord_polar()
plt
```

Comment: thanks for the input, however, it doesnt look like the input has the dots connected still with the code provided

Comment: I tested it on cars and it worked. Consider adding missing data (specifically, user_df) to your original post in order to make it reproducible?